# Происходит вывод всех данных из таблицы mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

у меня есть база mysql и в ней есть 2 таблицы:

1. users
2. receipts

у обеих есть столбец id, также у таблицы receipts есть столбец note.

в php я делаю сравнение по id и вывожу данные пользователю из столбца note.

Сейчас у меня выводится разом все данные из поля note

```
<?php

if ( $sql = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT `id` FROM `users`') == $sql2 = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT `id` FROM `receipts`')) {
    $sql2 = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT `note` FROM `receipts`'); 
    
  
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2)) {
    echo "{$result['note']}";}
```

что я делаю не так?

в php я новичок.

Comment: Что именно вы хотите получить?

Comment: *в php я делаю сравнение по id* поясните подробнее. у рецептов те же id, что и у пользователей?

Comment: в php я делаю сравнение по id поясните подробнее. у рецептов те же id, что и у пользователей? – Максим Степанов - Да, те же.

Answer (score 0):

Непонятно зачем 2 раза делать SELECT, почему нельзя использовать _JOIN ?

```
SELECT b.note FROM receipts AS b LEFT_JOIN users AS a ON b.id = a.id
```

А дальше:

```
<?php
if ($sql = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT b.note FROM receipts AS b LEFT_JOIN users AS a ON b.id = a.id')) {
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo $result['note'];
    }
}
```